# java socket Object memory leak

Tags: java, sockets, stream, memory-leaks, objectoutputstream

i've a memory leak problem on java Socket Object communication.

this is my send thread.

```
    // create a new thread to send the packet
@Override
public synchronized void run() {

    if(!genericSocket.isConnected()){
        if(logger.isEnabled())
            logger.logMessage(PFLogging.LEVEL_WARN, "Socket is close");
        return;
    }

    int retry = 0;
    boolean packetSent = false;

    synchronized (objWriter) {
        while ((retry < RETRY) && (!packetSent) && (genericSocket.isConnected())) {
            try {
                objWriter.writeObject(bean);

                objWriter.flush();



                // Try until the cache is reset and the memory is free
                /*
                boolean resetDone = false;
                while(!resetDone) {
                    try {
                        objWriter.reset();
                        resetDone = true;
                    } catch (IOException r) {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    }
                }
                */

                // No error and packet sent
                continuousError = 0;
                packetSent = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continuousError++;

                if(logger.isEnabled())
                    logger.logMessage(PFLogging.LEVEL_ERROR, "Continuous Error [" + continuousError + "] sending message [" + e.getMessage() + "," + e.getCause() + "]");

                // control the number of continuous errors
                if(continuousError >= CONTINUOUS_ERROR) {
                    if(logger.isEnabled())
                        logger.logMessage(PFLogging.LEVEL_WARN, "I close the socket");
                    genericSocket.disconnect();
                }

                // next time is the time!
                retry++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the cache, when i sent about i packet per ms grow and grow!

if i add the commented part the cache is clean but when i need to send an async long message (about 3000 char) i see that the other message are lost!

There's another way to clean the cache without reset it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObjectOutputStream.reset() is not avoidable as it is the only means of clearing local hash tables, you can refer java source code for ObjectOutputStream for details of what happens in reset(), or else you will get OutOfMemoryError eventually

But you can very well implement a function like

```
private void writeObject(Object obj, ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException
    {
        synchronized(oos)
        {
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
            oos.reset();
        }
    }
```

However you must ensure that all writes to ObjectOutputStream happens through this method.

Answer (score 1):

the only solution i find is, first of starting a sending thread, to check if the thread pool is empty and in that case i reset the output stream.
I run the software all this night to check this.

Thanks all!

Matteo

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` periodically to clear the object cache for the stream.

You could even use it after sending every object. ;)

Comment: I now but if i reset the buffer there's many cases i lost packet (this socket is used for async and sync message)

Comment: @MatteoGatto reset() does not cause packet loss.

Comment: @MatteoGatto can cause you to send the same object multiple times. A common mistake with streams is to write or read via two different Streams such as ObjectOutputStream and PrintWriter or two ObjectOutputStreams. This will result in a corruption of the data.

Answer (score 0):

ciao :),

after ObjectOutputStream.flush() you can saftely use ObjectOutputStream.reset()

unless you are using the objWriter somwhere in another thread without using the synchronized (objWriter) statement.
In this case the best way IMHO is to use the objWriter in a thread, it will send object from a syncornized queue (see Queue sub-class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html, for example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) that is filled from the other thread (remeber to use object.clone(), because the objcet itself isn't syncornized it can be modified by other thread while you are writing it or is in queue! if you clone it your clone will be a safe copy).

That way you don't need synchronized statment because data-flow between thread and ObjectOutputStream is already synchronized, and you will be less error-prone

Comment: Ok thanks i see that without sync the comunication is faster but the original problem is always here :)

Comment: with my code MAYBE you are optimizing, but first of all you are making your code very much less error prone.